# How to show the jQuery datepicker on mouse over a DIV?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div defined in my HTML. I would like the datepicker to display when the user mousesover the DIV. When the user selects a date, I will process that internally.

```
<div id="dp-trigger">Text text</div>
```

js is like this:

```
$("#dp-trigger").datepicker({
    minDate: -1,
    maxDate: "+2M",
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        // Do something with the date here.
    }
});

$('#dp-trigger).mouseover(function () {
    $("#epgGridDate").datepicker("show");
});
```

I can see the mouseover fire but never see the datepicker. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the closing quote which is messing up the javascript.

```
$('#dp-trigger').mouseover(function () {
```

Otherwise it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/7g658/2/

Comment: In my code I have the closing quote around the element name. I saw in jsfiddle, however, that you didn't have   $("#epgGridDate").datepicker("show"); just $("#epgGridDate").datepicker(); - Taking out the "show" fixed it for me. Thanks!